# Justify election phase tabs with long translated names to the right

Tags: bug, design, election, localization, responsive-design

On the election page, the tabs are aligned weird for [non-English](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=primary) long enough translations:

> [image: Primary in Russian]

In that case, there isn't any margin between tabs and candidates count. I suggest to align (justify) all tab buttons here to the right side.

Compare with [English UI](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) where all tabs fit into a single line:

> [image: Primary in English]

To reproduce, you need to use a mobile device in narrow mode, or reduce the browser width to the minimum on desktop.

That's what I'm suggesting (one picture costs a thousand words):

> [image: Suggested view]

In this case, even the count of candidates can fit into a single line.

Comment: Nothing weird here. The screen is too narrow so the responsive design stacks the buttons vertically so there won't be horizontal scrollbar. That's the expected behavior. As for margin, adding it would also make the horizontal display with margin with isn't good.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard vertically is fine, but the alignment should be to the right (as used for single row), not to the left.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Or, in other words, have the buttons be right justified instead of left justified (but still on separate lines).

Comment: @Sonic no. Russian is not Right-to-Left, so I believe that for most people that would be really weird and confusing.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard how is the RtoL/LtoR property of the language relevant to buttons alignment? See the light blue bar above the buttons - in English buttons block aligned to the right, but in Russian (due to long enough translation and wrapping into several lines) to the left. Just align them to the right, that all what I'm asking about.